# cantidad de horas (en segundos) en un rango horario, y mostrarlo por intervalo

Tags: sql, datetime

tengo una tabla con 2 columnas, hora inicio y hora fin, usando coodigo en sql, primero he calculado los segundos entre ellos con un datediff, luego lo coloqué por intervalo de 30 minutos, ej:

hora_inicio     hora_fin      intervalo     dif_seg

10:25:28        10:25:53        10:00           25

10:47:30        10:48:50        10:30          80

el problema me surge cuandola hora inicio y la hora fin estan en diferentes intervalos:

hora_inicio     hora_fin      intervalo     dif_seg

11:28:30        11:32:10        11:00          220

Como ven, me sale que los 220 segundos estan en el intervalo de las 11:00, pero no es correcto, deberia, de alguna manera, crear dos intervalos, uno con 11:00 que tenga solo 90 segundos, y otro en el intervalo 11:30 que tenga 130 segundos. Y mas complicado aun, si hay muchos intervalos entre la hora inicio y hora fin.Gracias.

Para replicar:

```
create table tiempos(
fecha date,
eventlogstartdate datetime, 
eventlogenddate datetime,
seg int
)
go
INSERT INTO tiempos 
VALUES  ('2021-04-01', '2021-04-01 16:00:17.360', '2021-04-01 16:01:17.160',60),
        ('2021-04-01', '2021-04-01 16:01:17.160', '2021-04-01 16:01:29.910',12), 
        ('2021-04-01', '2021-04-01 16:28:04.147', '2021-04-01 16:40:44.430',760), 
        ('2021-04-01', '2021-04-01 16:53:03.413', '2021-04-01 16:53:06.680',3),
        ('2021-04-01', '2021-04-01 17:02:22.260', '2021-04-01 17:02:35.243',13);

select Fecha,eventlogstartdate,eventlogenddate,
right('00'+cast(datepart(hour,eventlogstartdate) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' + 
case when datepart(minute,eventlogstartdate) between 0 and 29 then '00' else '30' end intervalo,seg,
from [Tiempos]
```

Comment: Hola, sería bueno que introduzcas el código que tienes hasta el momento y si es posible, una forma de poder replicar tu problema.

Comment: Si, ya esta añadido. Gracias.

En el ej dado, de alguna manera tendria que terminar con los intervalos algo asi:

16:00  188 segundos
16:30  647 segundos 
17:00  13 segundos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para construir esta solución asumí que en cada registro eventlogstartdate y eventlogenddate pertenecen al mismo día.

Primero utilizo una query recursiva para generar todos los posibles intervalos de 30 minutos de un día.

Luego en otra query calculo el intervalo al que pertence cada eventlogstartdate y cada eventlogenddate. Además obtengo la hora de cada una de dichas fechas/hora. Esta query se puede obviar, pero la uso porque hace mas legible la query principal.

En la query principal vinculo ambas queries anteriores, de manera tal que por cada fila en tiempos voy a tener tantas filas como intervalos haya entre eventlogstartdate y eventlogenddate. Utilizo dos `CASE` anidados para calcular los segundos de acuerdo a eventlogstartdate y eventlogenddate y los intervalos

```
WITH intervalos AS (SELECT cast('00:00' AS time) AS hora

                              UNION ALL
                              
                              SELECT dateadd(minute, 30, hora) AS hora
                              FROM intervalos 
                              WHERE hora <= cast('23:00' AS time)),
                              
     sqTiempos AS (SELECT 
                          fecha,
                          eventlogstartdate,
                          eventlogenddate,
                          cast(dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, eventlogstartdate) / 30 * 30, 0) AS time) AS intStart,
                          cast(dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0, eventlogenddate) / 30 * 30, 0) AS time) AS intEnd,
                          cast(eventlogstartdate AS time) AS startTime,
                          cast(eventlogenddate AS time) AS endTime
                   FROM tiempos)


SELECT 
       t.fecha,
       t.eventlogstartdate,
       t.eventlogenddate,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), i.hora, 108) AS intervalo,
       CASE WHEN intStart = intEnd
            THEN datediff(second, t.eventlogstartdate, t.eventlogenddate) 
            ELSE 
                CASE WHEN startTime >= i.hora
                         THEN datediff(second, startTime, dateadd(minute, 30, i.hora))
                     WHEN startTime <= i.hora AND endTime >= dateadd(minute, 30, i.hora)
                         THEN  datediff(second, dateadd(minute, -30, i.hora), i.hora)
                     ELSE datediff(second, i.hora, endTime) 
                     END
            END AS seg
FROM sqTiempos t
INNER JOIN intervalos i ON i.hora BETWEEN intStart AND intEnd
ORDER BY t.eventlogstartdate, i.hora;
```

Resultado (para los datos de ejmplo de la pregunta):

| fecha | eventlogstartdate | eventlogenddate | intervalo | seg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01 16:00:17.360 | 2021-04-01 16:01:17.160 | 16:00 | 60 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01 16:01:17.160 | 2021-04-01 16:01:29.910 | 16:00 | 12 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01 16:28:04.147 | 2021-04-01 16:40:44.430 | 16:00 | 116 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01 16:28:04.147 | 2021-04-01 16:40:44.430 | 16:30 | 644 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01 16:53:03.413 | 2021-04-01 16:53:06.680 | 16:30 | 3 |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01 17:02:22.260 | 2021-04-01 17:02:35.243 | 17:00 | 13 |

Comment: Supongo que para un query mas realista deberia funcionar para registros en dias distintos, pero para efectos de mi necesidas cumple perfectamente, muchisimas gracias.

Comment: De nada @RodolfoMancisidor!